# Android app crashes on second run

Tags: android, crash

I have been working on my app and it runs on the simulator fine.  I loaded it into my phone and now I have a problem.  It runs fine when I first start it and also if I pick home and then restart it; however, if I use the back arrow and then restart it it crashes on that time, but will work out the next time I start it.  I think it has to do with some kind of memory build up, but I verified onDestroy is being called, I figured that deletes everything my program created, right?

Comment: If you provide the logcat output it will be easier to track the problem.

Comment: Send logcat, and make sure you don't leave threads and or unmanaged cursors active.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I was loading a lot of bitmaps in Oncreate(), I did not realize that I had to release them under onDestroy().  I'm still a little surprized I have to do this as the API says they will be picked up by garbage collection when there is no longer a reference to them...like when my program is closed...